# validation rule is not working as expected with ISBLANK

Tags: validation-rule

Hi Friends i got a requirement like when demo status picklist is completed and if they try to change unit potential and i have to whit list some profiles.i have to thrown an error

```
IF(ISNULL(Number_of_Units__c),null, AND(ISCHANGED(Number_of_Units__c),ISPICKVAL( Demo_Status__c,'Completed'),
$Profile.Name <> "Sales Manager No IP restriction",$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator" ))
```

Everything is works fine.But i got a requirement like to customize this rule will fire only if Number_of_Units__c is not blank.I tried both isblank and is null doesn't works.And Number_of_Units__c is a number field.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is we have to give access to the user if unit potential is blank or zero.So,I Include **PRIORVALUE**.So,it throws validation if user try to update Number_of_Units__c > 0 only.

```
AND ( 
PRIORVALUE(Number_of_Units__c) > 0, 
ISCHANGED(Number_of_Units__c), 
ISPICKVAL( Demo_Status__c,'Completed'), 
$Profile.Name <> "Sales Manager No IP restriction", 
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator" 
)
```

It works very well.

Comment: your question is not clear, anyway

Comment: But after i updated my question. I mention this rule will fire only Number_of_Units__c not blank and Number_of_Units__c is a number field too and even i mention  ISBLANK doesn't working in my case